# XPath matching attribute and content of an element

Tags: xpath, matching

Can anyone help with the following XPath question? Given the node-set:

```
<table> 
  <rows>
    <row>
      <value column="Product">Coal</value>
      <value column="Quantity">10000</value>
    </row>
    <row>
      <value column="Product">Iron</value>
      <value column="Quantity">5000</value>
    </row>
    <row>
      <value column="Product">Ore</value>
      <value column="Quantity">4000</value>
    </row>
  </rows>
</table>
```

I want to query to find the node sub-set with a given product name. Note that the product name is being supplied by an attribute of the current node being processed (i.e. "@name"). So when the @name attribute has the value of "Coal" I would expect this to be returned:

```
<row>
  <value column="Product">Coal</value>
  <value column="Quantity">10000</value>
</row>
```

This is what I've come up with; I know it's wrong, because I don't get anything back.

```
$table/rows/row[value[@column='Product'][text()=@name]]
```

</code>

Comment: you could post actual XML with the angle brackts, if you just highlight the lines of XML and then press the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar. No need to manually replace all angle brackets with &lt; and &gt; .....

Comment: Ohhh, thanks for the tip. I knew there should have been an easier way :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are obviously missing the `current()` function

```
$table/rows/row[value[@column='Product'] = current()/@name]
```

Within an XPath predicate (i.e. within square brackets) the context node is the node the predicate is applied to.

In your case, when you say `$table/rows/row[x=@name]`, then `@name` refers to the `@name` attribute of `row`. Which has no `@name` attribute, so the predicate always evaluates to `false` for all nodes.

`current()` returns the current XSLT context node to help in exactly this case.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Tomalak. I came up with a work-around by copying the @name attribute out to a variable first, but yours is much nicer.

Comment: I don't think that you need current(), maybe I am wrong, but isn't current() the same as '.'?

Comment: @vtd: Yes, you are wrong. If `current()` were the same as `.`, then `current()` would not exist. ;)

Comment: when would they not be equal then?

Comment: @vtd: Outside of an XPath predicate.